# Bash, Move file help in variable

Tags: bash

```
for i in *.txt
do 
    #Text files 
    echo  $i
    #checking for existing files
    if [ -f ~/txt/$i ] 
    then 
        j=1
        #Stripping .txt from the files
        temp=${i%".txt"}
        #appending filaname with counter "($j)"
        i=$temp\($j\).txt
        #move to folder /txt
        mv $i ~/txt
    else
        mv $i ~/txt
    fi
done
```

My loop checks a folder for an existing file, if that file name exists, the file name is appended (ex (1), (2) etc. 
Once the file name has been renamed and it is held in `$i` I try to mv it but I'm getting:
`mv: cannot stat 'list(1).txt': No such file or directory`

I tried `mv {$i} ~/txt`, `mv [$i] ~/txt` etc...no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I notice you use `j=1`, but you never increment that value. What are your intentions here? I suspect this program doesn't do what you want in more ways than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the actually name of the file here:

```
  i=$temp\($j\).txt
```

Instead, use a new variable for the new name. Something like this.

```
  newname=$tmp\($j\).txt
  #move to folder /txt
  mv $i ~/txt/$newname
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to do. I ran my script and the move worked. Thank you very much Freddie!

Comment: Go ahead and accept this as the answer if you think it solved your problem. But it looks like there could be other potential problems in your code as jwd has pointed out in his comment and his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> Once the file has been renamed and it is held in `$i`...

But that is wrong - the file has *not* been renamed at this point.
You manipulated some text in a variable. That does not have any effect on the filesystem until you run a command, such as through using `mv`.

Also, in your `else` statement, it is not clear to me why you are running `mv` on a file that does not exist (fails the `-f` test).

I had some code here, but from reading your program again, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, exactly...