# How to read a number of input from a user to change file name that alright exists in the directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I know how to let the user type in a number (e.g., “1”) from the keyboard but the part i do not know is that how can I rename the filename extension of the specified file (i.e.,“File_1.txt”) from “txt” to “bak” and copy it to the “Backup” folder.

Comment: Lookup the `mv` command - will do both actions you need.

Comment: Yes i know but the problem i do not understand is that how can i specify this with a number? because my files are File_1.txt etc. How can i make this so the number can specify the file?

Comment: You just have to have it in a variable and pass it to `mv`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993220)

Comment: I was thinking to much outside of the box. Thank you for your response. I have manage to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  "Which file you want to change:"

read i

mv File_"$i".txt File_"$i".bak

cp your root/File_"$i".bak your root/Backup
```

Comment: Yeah but i only need to copy it not to move it...or i missing anything here?

Comment: Ah got it, misunderstood your requirement sorry